# Is there a way for a SPA to check if there's a proxy and handling it properly?

Tags: vue.js, proxy, axios, single-page-application

We have developped a SPA SaaS and went to a soft production launch recently.

Everything was fine until one of our customers told us they had trouble using the app.
Once they open the app, the first request to our backend triggers their proxy credential prompt. Hopefully on the login request.
They have to enter their proxy credentials to let the request go. All subsequent requests are passing properly and they can use the app.

**The problem is:**

When they stop using the app, close the browser and then come back the day after, the persistent login tries to connect them to our backend, but the proxy credentials prompt is not triggered and the request fails. All subsquent requests fail also.

For it work again, they have to delete all app data in chrome (so the service worker is unregistered, the localstorage and cache are cleared). The next api call will trigger their proxy credentials prompt and they will be able to work again.

So is there any way for the app to know if the proxy is set or not ? Any way of triggering the proxy prompt if not set or whatever ?

I don't exactly know how those proxies work and we have zero access to the proxy settings.
It surely is something with the credentials expiration after some time but that's all we can figure out right now. Maybe we could monitor some params in the request headers ?

We are using VueJS with axios for the requests.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is when user session credentials get expired, your UI is not handling redirection to login page. When the user login for the first time you should store that the user has logged in successfully in browser localstorage. If your server returns `401` error code, you can delete the flag and redirect the user to login page. You can achieve that using meta fields in router.

Check out this link on how to use meta fields https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem here. We don't have issues with our persistent login functionnality. The whole login/credential flow is working flawlessly. The issue is related to the proxy credentials which we don't control. The prompt is a native chrome prompt not related to our app. It just intercepts the very first call to our backend, asks for credentials and then authorize our requests.

Comment: I'm not sure I can be of any help with that. Also why down vote? I made a guess based on your description!